# VSCode shortcut to cycle through changed (git) blocks in current file

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In Sublime Text with the GitGutter plugin you can add the following keybindings:

```
{ "keys": ["super+["], "command": "git_gutter_prev_change" },
{ "keys": ["super+]"], "command": "git_gutter_next_change" },
```

This will allow you to jump your cursor through the changed sections of the open file. Useful if you jump into a large file and just want to go to the exact section(s) you're working on.

In VSCode, I know you can use `Git: Open Change` command (`workbench.action.git.globalOpenChange`) to switch to the diff view, then the `workbench.action.compareEditor.nextChange` and `previousChange` commands to cycle. I am aware you can edit while in the diff view, but I would rather never leave the editor view.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, but it's tracked by this feature request: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18059